# How to cache Firebase data in Flutter?

Tags: firebase, caching, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

In my app I build a list of objects using data from Firebase. Inside a StreamBuilder, I check if the snapshot has data. If it doesen't, I am returning a simple Text widget with "Loading...". My problem is that if I go to another page in the app, and then come back, you can see for a split second that it says 'Loading...' in the middle of the screen, and it is a bit irritating. I am pretty sure it is downloading the data from Firebase, and building the widget every time I come back to that page. And if I don't do the check for data, it gives me a data that I am trying to access data from null.

Is there a way to cache the data that was already downloaded, and if there has been no change in the data from Firebase, then just use the cached data?

Heres a redacted version of my code:

```dart
class Schedule extends StatefulWidget implements AppPage {
  final Color color = Colors.green;
  @override
  _ScheduleState createState() => _ScheduleState();
}

class _ScheduleState extends State<Schedule> {
  List<Event> events;
  List<Event> dayEvents;
  int currentDay;
  Widget itemBuilder(BuildContext context, int index) {
    // Some Code
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text("Loading...");
          }
          events = new List(snapshot.data.documents.length);
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(i);

            events[i] = Event(
              name: doc["name"],
              start: DateTime(
                doc["startTime"].year,
                doc["startTime"].month,
                doc["startTime"].day,
                doc["startTime"].hour,
                doc["startTime"].minute,
              ),
              end: DateTime(
                doc["endTime"].year,
                doc["endTime"].month,
                doc["endTime"].day,
                doc["endTime"].hour,
                doc["endTime"].minute,
              ),
              buildingDoc: doc["location"],
              type: doc["type"],
            );
          }
          events.sort((a, b) => a.start.compareTo(b.start));
          dayEvents = events.where((Event e) {
            return e.start.day == currentDay;
          }).toList();
          return ListView.builder(
            itemBuilder: itemBuilder,
            itemCount: dayEvents.length,
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: On what platform are you running this app? And what plugin are you using to access Firestore? On iOS and Android the [FlutterFire plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore-library.html) should already be caching the data locally once you access it. When you first open the stream on a collection, the data should be added to the cache. Subsequent calls to `stream()` on that same collection should 'immediately` return data from the local cache, and then potentially later fire again with updates from the server.

Comment: The data coming from the local cache, if it's enabled, doesn't appear in your app instantly.  You do have to wait for the local cache to satisfy the query, if it can.  If you want instant results, store things in memory and don't perform another query with the SDK.

Answer (score 14):

You can use the the following code to define the source you want to retrieve data from. This will search either in local cache or on the server, not both. It works for all `get()` parameters, no matter if it is a search or document retrieval.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection").doc("doc").get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache))
```

To check if the search has data in cache, you need to first run the search against cache and if there is no result, run it against the server.
I found project [firestore_collection](https://github.com/furkansarihan/firestore_collection) to use a neat extension that can greatly simplify this process.

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

// https://github.com/furkansarihan/firestore_collection/blob/master/lib/firestore_document.dart
extension FirestoreDocumentExtension on DocumentReference {
  Future<DocumentSnapshot> getSavy() async {
    try {
      DocumentSnapshot ds = await this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
      if (ds == null) return this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
      return ds;
    } catch (_) {
      return this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }
  }
}

// https://github.com/furkansarihan/firestore_collection/blob/master/lib/firestore_query.dart
extension FirestoreQueryExtension on Query {
  Future<QuerySnapshot> getSavy() async {
    try {
      QuerySnapshot qs = await this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
      if (qs.docs.isEmpty) return this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
      return qs;
    } catch (_) {
      return this.get(GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }
  }
```

If you add this code, you can simply change the `.get()` command for both documents and queries to `.getSavy()` and it will automatically try the cache first and only contact the server if no data can be locally found.

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection("collection").doc("doc").getSavy();
```

Comment: This answer is really cool.  However, I was doing this so at to increase the performance of my app (on the assumption that a fetch from the cache would be faster than a fetch from the server), and making this change makes zero to negligible performance increase.  I created a whole benchmark system to test this  - super disappointing that a local cache fetch is no faster than a server fetch when done this way.

Comment: @kris Good find, thanks for the insight! Caching on Firebase reads is often used is to reduce costs for data that rarely changes.

Answer (score 10):

To be sure whether the data is coming from Firestore's local cache or from the network, you can do this:

```
          for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
            DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(i);
            print(doc.metadata.isFromCache ? "NOT FROM NETWORK" : "FROM NETWORK");
```

In the case you described you are probably going to still see the loading screen when its "NOT FROM NETWORK". This is because it does take some time to get it from the local cache. Soon you will be able to ask for the [query's metadata](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/35550#issuecomment-508247807) for cases with empty results.

Like others suggested, you can cache the results and you won't see this. First you can try to cache it in the Widget using something like:

```
  QuerySnapshot cache; //**

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: StreamBuilder(
        initialData: cache, //**
        stream: Firestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot.hasData) {
            return Text("Loading...");
          }
          cache = snapshot.data; //**
```

This will make your widget remember the data. However, if this does not solve your problem, you would have to save it not in this widget but somewhere else. One option is to use the `Provider` widget to store it in a variable that lives beyond the scope of this particular widget.

Probably not related, but it's also a good idea to move the `Firestore.instance.collection('events').snapshots()` to `initState()`, save the reference to the stream in a private field and use that it `StreamBuilder`. Otherwise, at every build() you may be creating a new stream. You should be ready for `build()` calls that happen many times per second, whatever the reason.

Comment: "Like others suggested, you can cache the results and you won't see this." How would I actually go about doing this?

Comment: @Marco looking for something like this for firebase ?https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_cache_store

Answer (score 2):

### Using Generics

Appending to [@James Cameron](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1424378/james-cameron)'s answer above; I found myself in a situation where, said implementation removed my typecast from `withConverter`. So, the below adds the generic types back into the functions.

***main.dart***

```dart
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

extension FirestoreDocumentExtension<T> on DocumentReference<T> {
  Future<DocumentSnapshot<T>> getCacheFirst() async {
    try {
      var ds = await get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
      if (!ds.exists) return get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
      return ds;
    } catch (_) {
      return get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }
  }
}

extension FirestoreQueryExtension<T> on Query<T> {
  Future<QuerySnapshot<T>> getCacheFirst() async {
    try {
      var qs = await get(const GetOptions(source: Source.cache));
      if (qs.docs.isEmpty) return get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
      return qs;
    } catch (_) {
      return get(const GetOptions(source: Source.server));
    }
  }
}
```

***use_case.dart***
The implementation below would not compile with James example, as `DocumentSnapshot<Object?> is not a subset of DocumentSnapshot<UserModel>`. So, by adding the generic parameters back in, we can ensure that this extension maintains any type casts.

```dart
Future<DocumentSnapshot<UserModel>> userInfo() async {
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .doc("${path_to_user_model_doc}")
      .withConverter<UserModel>(
        fromFirestore: (snapshot, _) => UserModel.fromJson(snapshot.data()!),
        toFirestore: (userModel, _) => userModel.toJson(),
      )
      .getCacheFirst();
}
```

***pubspec.yaml***

```yaml
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.1 <3.0.2"
dependencies:
  cloud_firestore: ^3.1.17
```