# Flutter: Not stable output in getting my array of data in Firestore when going back

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm experiencing a quite not stable respond in getting my array of data. I'm showing this data in a list of card. I'm saying not stable because everytime I go to another navigation in my app then I'll go back to that nav where I output my data. It shows a red back ground first then for a mil of seconds it shows the data. Anyone know how to fix this? I'm just new in flutter / android. Please help.

For the red background it shows this on terminal and output the data that I'm getting.

```
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<QuerySnapshot, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot>>#dac03):
The getter 'documents' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: documents
```

My code:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: db.collection('ACTIVITIES').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  final issuesList = snapshot.data.documents
                      .map((doc) => doc['Issue'].map<Widget>((issue) => buildItem(issue)).toList())
                      .toList();
                  return Column(
                      children: issuesList.expand<Widget>((issue) => issue).toList()
                  );
                })
```

My db structure:

[image]

Please Help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you're facing is that inside `StreamBuilder`, `snapshot.data` is `null` and then the data arrives. That's why you see the red screen with the error and then it works normally.

First of all, when you use a `StreamBuilder` you should check if `snapshot.data` has something and then start using the data. You could use `snapshot.hasData`, like this:

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: db.collection('ACTIVITIES').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(...);
    }
    return Text('Loading...');
  },
)
```

With this now you'll see `'Loading...'` instead of the red screen with the error, and when the data arrives you'll see the data normally.

Now, when you go to another screen and you come back, the `build()` method triggers again and the `StreamBuilder` will get the data from the stream again. Even if Firestore caches the data, it might take a while to be available so you'll get `null` and then the cached data will arrive. It won't take too long like the first time, but you'll probably see `'Loading...'`.

To avoid showing `'Loading...'` after the first time you received the data, you could use a memory cache and set that as `initialData` on the `StreamBuilder`, like this:

```
QuerySnapshot cache; // declare this outside build()

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  initialData: cache,
  stream: db.collection('ACTIVITIES').snapshots(),
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      return Column(...);
    }
    cache = snapshot.data;
    return Text('Loading...');
  },
)
```

With this I think you could solve your problem. If you want to see more suggestions, check this: [How to cache Firebase data in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386003/how-to-cache-firebase-data-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks again sir @Pablo. Got it working, you're really a life savior!