# Is it possible to add only new documents to Cloud Firestore cache?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have an app that has 50k - 60k document reads a day and I can't afford another plan now, so I'm looking for a way to optimize reads, getting less reads possible I can.

The database has 4 collections with some subcollections, I think I might have around 1000 documents in the whole server.

It is there anyway: I can read documents from cloud Firestore (first time the user opens the app) and store on the Firestore cache, after that, make the app only load data from Firestore cache, and if there is a new document(s), it reads these documents only, store to the cache, and keep reading from the cache?

The app could only load data from cache (using the parameter "source") and never directly from Firestore, if possible.

```
Firestore.instance.collection("images").getDocuments(source: Source.cache);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is is there anyway: I can read documents from cloud Firestore (first time the user opens the app) and store on the Firestore cache

That's the default behavior. According to the official documentation regarding [Firestore offline persistence](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/enable-offline):

> - For Android and iOS, offline persistence is enabled by default. To disable persistence, set the PersistenceEnabled option to false.
> - For the web, offline persistence is disabled by default. To enable persistence, call the enablePersistence method. Cloud Firestore's cache isn't automatically cleared between sessions. Consequently, if your web app handles sensitive information, make sure to ask the user if they're on a trusted device before enabling persistence.

So there is nothing special that you need to do. Once you open a stream on one of your collections, the data is added to the cache.

> after that, make the app only load data from Firestore cache, and if there is a new document(s), it reads these documents only, stores to the cache, and keeps reading from the cache?

That's again the default behavior, but this work as long as the documents in your database are not changed. If a document in the database is changed, you'll be charged with a document read for each document. The mechanism is the same.

Besides that, you can tell Firestore to read data only from the cache if needed, as explained in the answer from the following post:

- [How to cache Firebase data in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386003/how-to-cache-firebase-data-in-flutter)

Comment: But does it work in the same way for StreamBuilder(snapshots) and FutureBuilder(getDocuments) about updating only new documents?

Comment: Yes, that's the same mechanism.

Comment: I asked because looks like we cannot use parameter "cache" when using StreamBuilder, ".snapshot()", only FutureBuilder(.getDocuments(source: ?)) has.

Comment: I was referring to the billing part. Yes, in the case of `StreamBuilder` there is no way you can use parameter "cache". When you listen for realtime updates, you are listening for documents that are changed on the server. Once you get some updates, all documents are then cached on user's device.

Comment: I just tested now using StreamBuilder and FutureBuilder using print(document.metadata.isFromCache ? "NOT FROM NETWORK" : "FROM NETWORK"), opened the app for the first time, it prints "FROM NETWORK", closed the app and for the second time it prints "FROM NETWORK" again, so It's not automatically loading from cache even with no data changed in Cloud Firestore.

Comment: Without seeing the code that you are using, I cannot be much of a help. If you have a hard time when implementing this functionality or the code does not behave the way you expect, please post another fresh question using its own [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so I and other Firebase developers can help you.

Comment: Ok, I made another question showing some code and I think it has more details. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59455039/firestore-cache-not-working-even-if-no-data-has-changed

Comment: If you are offline a local copy will be created and any database write that is done while you are offline will be synced when you are online again. But then data will still be retrieved from the server

Comment: This answer contains wrong statements and leads to unexpected costs.
Alex, where did you find these info? Answering the part "if there is a new document(s), it reads these documents only, stores to the cache, and keeps reading from the cache?" you wrote "That's again the default behavior, but this work as long as the documents in your database are not changed".
This is not true. Persistence only let you access data when offline, it does *NOT* optimize reads from Firestore servers if online.
Even with persistence enabled, every time the app load it downloads from Firestore.

Comment: @tonjo Everything is I quote comes from the docs, as it is also mentioned in my answer. *Persistence only let you access data when offline, it does NOT optimize reads from Firestore servers if online.* That's correct but I have never said that is optimizing something in my answer. Please read it again.

Comment: @tonjo *Even with persistence enabled, every time the app load it downloads from Firestore.* That's **completely** wrong. If a document was read, it is written to the cache. If that document is **not** changed, the second time you read that document is from the cache. Image how would it be to pay for the same unchanged document every time I read it? That would be insane. If I read an unchanged document 1.000.000 times, I will pay 1.000.000 read operation? No, that's not gonna happen.

Comment: I got the official answer from firebase support, I'm happy to forward it to you if you desire:
*[...] with the get method is when things get tricky your app will try to get the data from the server (despite you have it locally) it verifies if you are either connected or not, if you are not it will give you the cached data(since the request to get the latest data will time out), otherwise it will fetch (despite the data hasn't changed) all the documents requested.*
So, @AlexMamo, my assumptions and deductions from my tests were right, your answer is wrong.

Comment: Honestly I don't understand why you keep saying that and you are not able to show where your behaviour is documented.

Comment: @tonjo Thanks for sharing this with me. I'll do more tests. In the meanwhile, you can check Doug's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60062248/firebase-firestore-snapshot-read-count/60062304#60062304), regarding the same topic.