# Firebase Firestore snapshot read count

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to optimize the number of reads my app makes on Firesbase and reviewing the way I use snapshot to monitor real time changes. Imagine I have a snapshot returning the 10 latest documents like the following:

```
db.collection("cities")
.where("state", "==", "CA").
.orderBy('dateadded', 'desc').limit(10)
.onSnapshot(function(snapshot) {
    ...
})
```

The doc says

> The snapshot handler will receive a new query snapshot every time the
>   query results change (that is, when a document is added, removed, or
>   modified).

Does that mean that every time the query changes I will be billed 10 reads? In this example if a new city is added (so with the latest 'dateadded', so coming first in the query) will it be 1 (just the new city) or 10 reads (the full query).

As a side question where I can see the exact number of read I am at (live so I can test a function and see the corresponding number of reads). The IAM and Admin/Quota seems to provide that under "reads request per day" but it is not live...

I am referring to the Firestore snapshot as described at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If 1 document changes in query results, you will be billed 1 read.  You are not billed for documents that are unchanged. The query snapshot object merely reuses the document data that was in memory from the prior set of results.

Comment: Ok. But note that in the example I give, unchanged documents actually change position in the query result (1st becomes 2nd, 2nd becaomes 3rd and so on) - is your answer still the same? Sill 1 read?

Comment: And any clue regarding my question on following live my consumption?

Comment: One query is one read, regardless of how many documents it returns. Snapshot holds the results of that query. If you add 1 document or 20, the snapshot of the query for 10 documents changes because there are new documents. So it has to run the query for 10 documents again instead of using it's cache, but it is a single query for 10 documents. That's why it's only 1 read, as Doug says, not 10. So your question: still one read? Yes, still one read.

Comment: 1 query 1 read??? That makes no sense to me... If my query reads my entire collection with !M+ doc, that cant be 1 read!

Comment: One query is actually **at least one read**, so if it returned 0 documents it will still cost 1 read, in order to cover the cost of consulting the index.  It will cost 1 read for each returned document otherwise.

Comment: @DougStevenson, "It will cost 1 read for each returned document otherwise", but regarding my initial question then you seem to mean that my snapshot will cost me 10 read each time it triggers, right?

Comment: You will initially be billed 10, then 1 for each document changed in the results after that, for as long as the listener stays active.

Comment: This is only partially true, you are not billed for documents that are unchanged as long as client stays connected. From official docs:
*Also, if the listener is disconnected for more than 30 minutes (for example, if the user goes offline), you will be charged for reads as if you had issued a brand-new query.*. So be careful
Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#operations