# Firebase Firestore reads on streams

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, stream

I am using Firestore stream in my flutter app. The data is user profiles so I need to filter it as needed. My initial data stream is as follows

```
Stream s = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);
```

and when I have to filter data, I do

```
setState((){

s = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('name',isEqualTo:"MyName")
        .snapshots(includeMetadataChanges: true);

});
```

This works fine but my concern is reads, I know that data is cached and is read from server only if something changes but I don't know of streams.

I tried monitoring the usage on firebase but due to the app being in production I couldn't measure anything properly.

And if filtering by changing stream does cause reads on firebase then what else can I do to filter data from cache.

One thing I thought off was storing everything locally but storing data of thousands of users locally is impractical.

Answer (score 1):

> A stream is a sequence of asynchronous events. It is like an
> asynchronous Iterable—where, instead of getting the next event when
> you ask for it, the stream tells you that there is an event when it is
> ready.
> From Dart (https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams)

A stream is a continues datastream that closes when the class is terminated or by canceling the stream object:

```
streamSub.cancel();
```

You can use a stream in a streambuilder. Every time a change is applied to any of the documents, it rebuilds the builder.

```
StreamBuilder(
   stream: stream,
   builder: (BuildContext content, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
   }
)
```

> If 1 document changes in query results, you will be billed 1 read. You are not billed for documents that are unchanged. The query snapshot object merely reuses the document data that was in memory from the prior set of results. **By Doug Stevenson** (https://stackoverflow.com/a/60062304/9142870)