# Do not pull document from firestore if I've already pulled it flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am making a quiz app. It pulls questions from Firestore. Right now, when someone finishes a question, goes to another screen, and returns to the quiz area, they will see the same question because I am pulling documents from Firestore in order. Is there any way to prevent pulling the same documents?

Right now, I have a ChangeNotifierProvider wrapped around a List of document IDs and I check if the next question's ID is on that list. If it is, I move to the next one. This seems awfully inefficient and I was wondering if there was a better method.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem here.  It will help if you show pictures and code that isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: @doug Hi Doug! I have questions saved as documents in Firestore, and if I pull a document, I do not want to pull it again

Answer (score 0):

From [How to Cache Firebase Data with Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386003/how-to-cache-firebase-data-in-flutter)

On iOS and Android the FlutterFire plugin should already be caching the data locally once you access it. When you first open the stream on a collection, the data should be added to the cache. Subsequent calls to stream() on that same collection should 'immediately` return data from the local cache, and then potentially later fire again with updates from the server.