# Collect all the data from the database an access it from anywhere

Tags: database, flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am developing a Flutter app using Firebase as a database. I want to reduce the read operation because every time user clicks on the screen it reads again. So I want to get all the data and access it from anywhere to reduce read operation. How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can use cache in firebase
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57386003/how-to-cache-firebase-data-in-flutter

Comment: It's hard to suggest how to improve your code without seeing it. Can you edit your question to show the minimal code that reproduces the superfluous reads? Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance here drastically increases the chances that someone can help.